# Remove flag in CCFLAGS with Scons

Tags: scons

I've found examples replacing, but not removing flags from CCFLAGS in Scons. For example, if you have a high-level SConstruct file with a definition:

```
baseEnv.Append( CCFLAGS = [ '-Wall', '-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1' ])
```

And you want to remove that flag in a lower-level Sconscript file:

```
myEnv = baseEnv.Clone()
# Remove '-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1' flag from myEnv:CCFLAGS
```

How would you go about doing that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You use the remove method as seen below in your SConscript file:

```
myEnv=baseEnv.Clone()
if '-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1' in myEnv['CCFLAGS']:
    myEnv['CCFLAGS'].remove('-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1')
```

I tried this with SCons 2.3.0 and it works fine.

Comment: 2.3.0 is a pretty old version. Have you tried 3.0.4 which was recently released?

Comment: @bdbaddog That was the package I had in hands when I tested. I'll take a look at the recent release, too. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add "-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1", the SCons variable for adding/setting such is via CPPDEFINES (See: https://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-man.html#cv-CPPDEFINES ):

```
baseEnv.AppendUnique(CPPDEFINES=[{'_FORTIFY_SOURCE':1}])
```

Then you'd use the following to strip it out:

```
a['CPPDEFINES'] = [ x for x in env['CPPDEFINES'] if '_FORTIFY_SOURCE' not in x]
```